# Using Google API in Angular 2/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, youtube-data-api

A previous question here got me most of the way (hopefully) to getting this working, but I can't seem to get a Google API working from TypeScript. I'm basically following this example: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples

I'm not seeing an error, the method to run the API call just isn't getting fired.

I've installed the typings for gapi and gapi.auth. `initClient()` doesn't throw any errors, it just never seems to complete. The current user is signed in as a Google user, but not authorized for the API call yet. That's the next thing I was going to deal with, but right now the call isn't even being made. As you can see below, I added a logging line at the beginning of the method that isn't being called.

```
initGapiClient() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', this.initClient);
  }

  initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: '',
      discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest'],
      clientId: 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      this.updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
  }

  updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      this.listPlaylists();
    } else {
      alert("Can't sign in");          
    }
  }

  listPlaylists() {
    console.log("Called listPlaylists");
    ... 
    API call here
    ... 
  }
```

Comment: How do I install the typings for gapi and gapi.auth?

Comment: @Plastic npm install --save @types/gapi and also @types/gapi.auth2. Just Google it, you'll find these: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gapi.auth2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After messing around with this, I found that a better sample for my use case was this one: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/javascript-guide

Note that I am using the first suggestion as well:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(status => this.updateSigninStatus(status));
```

I was able to get everything working after I realized that I had to init gapi.auth with everything I wanted the first time--I thought I could just authorize again later with different scopes. I'm now doing it in index.html like this:

```
    var PROJECT_ID = 'projectname';
    var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var API_KEY = '1234';
    var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly';

    /**
    * Authorize Google Compute Engine API.
    */
    function authorization() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        immediate: false
      }, function(authResult) {
          if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            window.alert('Auth was successful!');
          } else {
            window.alert('Auth was not successful');
          }
        }
      );
     }
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
.then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      this.updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
```

to

```
.then(()=> {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSigninStatus.bind(this));

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      this.updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
```

if you use function your `this` will not refer to your component and passing a function as a parameter like `.listen(this.updateSigninStatus);` will also make the outer `this` to be binded to this function.

I suggest you to read: [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that link. I tried the change you suggested, but it hasn't resolved the problem. Anything inside "then" is still not being called. Even `console.log()` isn't being triggered. Postman shows the GET call to the discoveryDoc is working.

Comment: @beachCode if you are using chrome, you can check from the network tab in the developer tools (F12) to see whether it is actually making the request or not.

Comment: @echonax `.listen(() => this.updateSigninStatus());` is preferable in TypeScript because the callback will be typechecked.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes of course sir but I don't know in which callback parameter `listen` method gives the `isSignedIn` parameter that the `updateSigninStatus` method uses so I wanted stay on the safe side.

Comment: @echonax that is a fair point. I assume it must pass at least one potentially truthy value so actually I should have suggested `.listen(status => this.updateSigninStatus(status));`

Comment: Thanks again. I tried that change as well and I don't see any difference. The last network call is the Google API discovery call. No error...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯